# Laravel 5.4 - Update em tabelas relacionadas

Tags: laravel, sql-update

Qual o melhor jeito de fazer um *update* em duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo? Eu achava que era so chamar a tabela relacionada, mas quando eu faco isso so faz o *update* na tabela *servico* e não na do *cliente*.

Eu consegui fazer passando o id do cliente pra *view* e depois pegando ele e inserindo no *where* pra fazer o *update*(como mostra o outro exemplo), mas gostaria de saber se e possível fazer o *update* nas duas tabelas sem ficar informando o código da chave estrangeira.

CLIENTE CONTROLLER (Funcionando)

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $dataForm = $request->all();
    $cliente_id = $request->input('cliente_id');

    Servico::find($id)->update($dataForm);
    Cliente::find($cliente_id)->update($dataForm);

    return redirect()->route('index');
}
```

CLIENTE CONTROLLER (Nao funcionando)

```
  public function update(Request $request, $id)
   {
        $dataForm = $request->all();

        Servico::with('cliente')->find($id)->update($dataForm);

        return redirect()->route('index');
   }
```

MODEL CLIENTE

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cliente extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'clientes';
    protected $fillable = ['nome', 'fone'];
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function servicos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Servico');
    }
}
```

MODEL SERVICO

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Servico extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'servicos';
    protected $fillable = ['valor', 'descricao', 'cliente_id', 'data_fechamento'];
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'data_fechamento'];
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function cliente()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Cliente');
    }
}
```

Comment: Você quer Servico para Cliente aonde 1 serviço é de 1 cliente?

Comment: Isso, um servico pertence a 1 cliente,  mas um cliente pode ter varios servicos.

Comment: Quando eu for editar um servico, eu posso alterar as informacoes do servico(valor, descricao) e os dados do cliente(nome, fone).

Comment: Pode sim Diego. Normalmente, só não esqueça de configurar o `fillable`!

Comment: Deu certo @Diego?

Answer (score 3):

Carregue o `$servico`, atualize os campos, navegue pela relação `cliente()` e atualiza o `Cliente` da relação de `Servico`:

```
$servico = Servico::find($id) // busca o serviço
if ($servico) // verifica se serviço foi encontrado
{
    $servico->update($dataForm); // update serviço
    $servico->cliente()->update($dataForm); // update cliente da relação
}
```

***Referencia:*** [Eloquent: updates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#updates)